# Pythonic way to sort list of objects by a dict value (by key) contained within the object

Tags: python, sorting

I'm seeking advice on doing the following in a more pythonic way.

Consider:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_properties = {}
```

Suppose I've got a list which contains multiple MyObj instances:

```
mylist = [<__main__.MyObj object at 0x1005e3b90, ...]
```

Now i want to sort `mylist` based on the value of a certain key in `dict_properties` in MyObj.

What does work is:

```
mylist.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x.dict_properties['mykey'],
                            y.dict_properties['mykey']))
```

but that *hardly* feels **pythonic**.

Is there a better way (perhaps using `operator.attrgetter`)?

Comment: tags are not a reflection on the level of the person asking. No one claims that you're a beginner Christophe, but on any given day there would be at least a couple of question asking **exactly the same thing as you do**, and since answer is could be easily found in docs, it therefore is a question that needs to tagged [beginner]. Please stop removing this tag. Thanks.

Comment: if you doubt my claim about the frequency or duplicates please review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+sorting

Comment: I have a different opinion on the need for a 'beginner' tag on this question: unlike most other questions of this type, I provided a working way to do this and then specifically asked for alternative / other ways of doing this in a more 'pythonic' way. Seems the answer was obvious (only one approach in the answers) although it did not immediately occur to me that this was supposed to be the cleanest way =. But I'll just leave the tag then, since I've no interest in a (further) rollback/editing war.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x.dict_properties['mykey'])
```

is way simpler, and faster.  You could reach for `operator` and try to compose an `attrgetter` and an `itemgetter`, but a straightforward `lambda` (or `def`) seems simplest here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems this is indeed a very clean way of providing this functionality ;-)

Comment: Only negative point would be that this would not work below python 2.4, is it not? (although I doubt that there are still a lot of python installations around below that version).

Comment: @ChristopheD, yep, `key=` was introduced in 2.4 (whose final release was a bit more than 5 years ago). Anybody who needs to support 6-year-old or older versions should no doubt be expected to mention that fact explicitly, I imagine;-).

Comment: What, a use for the evil, functional lambda construct?!  Who would've thought?!

Comment: @Omnifarious, `def` would do just as well (as I mention in the answer, of course) -- I guess doing more Javascript inclines me to see both `def` and `lambda` as ugly, silly, needlessly limiting spellings of `function`, anyway (Javascript has it just right in this one case!-).

Answer (score 3):

I'd just do:

`mylist.sort(key=lambda o: o.dict_properties["kykey"])`

You could also overide **cmp** on the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I considered overriding cmp on the class but that would imply losing some of the dynamity of variably choosing 'mykey' (unless I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

If speed is an issue, then use decorate-sort-undecorate:

```
    mylist_decorated = [(elem.dict_properties['mykey'], elem) for elem in mylist]
    mylist_decorated.sort()
    mylist = [elem[1] for elem in mylist_decorated] # or zip(*mylist_decorated)[1] :)
```

- this way sort() can spread its wings.

Comment: This is pretty much what the key parameter of the sort method does for you.  If you are using Python < 2.4 then this would be a sensible way to do it, otherwise you are just making work for yourself.